# Web framework with static checking

Tags: web, type-systems

Most of the web frameworks available on the market allow a lot of dynamic features:

- You access session elements and request paramaters with untyped, typically, string keys
- You reference other pages with string literals, i.e. "post.html?id=%s"
- You create database queries inside of string literals
- Most web frameworks heavily rely on reflection to find stuff like controller actions, etc

Are there any web frameworks which support static checking for this things? And why this isn't implemented in any framework yet ?

P.S. IMO, this should be possible. We create Desktop GUI applications in a statically checkable (by language type system) way, why can't we do the same with web applications?

Comment: Most web frameworks for _what language_? Those using strongly typed languages are _certainly_ supported by some static analysis tools (Java and .NET come to mind).

Comment: @Oded For any language. Even though, Java and .NET are statically typed languages, all of web frameworks which I am aware of rely on dynamic features, and can't be called typesafe.

Comment: How are you suggesting to do static analysis of links coming for third party sites?

Comment: @Oded I didn't mean external sites. I wanted to validate intra-application links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only existing framework with such features is Yesod: http://www.yesodweb.com/
It's checks statically almost everything.